# Помогите с виджетом на tcl\tk

Tags: c, api, tcl

Пытаюсь запустить пример - [Clock widget on C](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15946)

После компиляции исходника получаю новый `tk.h`. 

Заменяю им старый `tk.h` в `"\\Tcl\include"`.
Как добавить новый виджет в программу? 
`pack clock` и `pack ocklock` - ничего не добавляет

Comment: Хм, по ходу tkl.tk кто-то взломал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем кто с этим столкнется:

1. Нужно указать компилятору С все папки включений и библиотек Tcl/Tk
2. Взять "нормальный" компилятор (аля GCC, g++) /*лично у меня в VS никак не получилось скомпилировать*/
3. На выходе - получаем файл динамической библиотеки (dll/so)
4. Запускаем wish
5. > wish>load filename[info sharedlibextension]
6. После загрузки библиотеки можно вызывать команды в том же wish:

   oclock .oc
     pack .oc
7. Получаем результат
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]